# Is it possible to extend a class with a static method in Kotlin or Java?

Tags: kotlin

I would like to create a Java `Instant` from a `Long` representing a nanosecond epoch. While `Instant` has nanosecond precision, the only way to do this would be to use the `nanoAdjustment` argument of `Instant.ofEpochSecond`:

```kotlin
val nanos: Long
val instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond(0, nanos)
```

But it would be more convenient and readable if I could simply do:

```kotlin
val nanos: Long
val instant = Instant.ofEpochNanos(nanos)
```

To achieve this, the only solution I could think of was

```kotlin
package util

object Instant {
    /** Obtains an [Instant] from nanoseconds. */
    fun ofEpochNanos(nanos: Long): Instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond(0, nanos)
}
```

Then I can call `Instant.ofEpochNanos`, but this is a hack. When I import the `util` package above and `import java.time.Instant`, I will end up with two unrelated objects with the same name: the `Instant` object above, and the `Instant` class from `java.time`.

So, is it possible to *actually* extend a class with a static method?

Comment: Are you familiar with [Kotlin extensions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/extensions.html)?

Comment: While I can use Kotlin extensions to add instance methods to `Instant`, I can only use Kotlin extensions to add static methods if the class has a companion object, which `Instant` (being a Java class) does not :(

Comment: Instantiating `Instant` can be considered a separate responsibility; just make it a separate (factory) class. It keeps the code clean and simple; no need to hack your way into a class or interface that is not yours. As for readability, I see no problem in: `val instant = InstantFactory.createFromNanos(nanos)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer, it seems, is no. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-11968

> *Can there be feature that will allow us to declare statically accessible members for Java classes too?*

> #### May 2022
>
> We’re continuing to work on the design and planning to present a specific proposal for public review.